# Asynchronously update UI

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous

I'm playing with asynchronous operations and my goal right now is very simple. I just want to update a text field at the beginning of a large computation, and the problem I'm facing is that the text field gets updated but only when `calculate()` returns, even though the method `computingMessage()` is called immediately:

```
private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;           
    annunciate();                
    calculate();
}

private void annunciate(){
    Thread updateUI = new Thread( new ThreadStart( computingMessage ));
    updateUI.Start();             
}

private void computingMessage(){
    txtVerification.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(
        () => txtVerification.Text = "Calculating..."
    ));                
}
```

Comment: You're blocking the UI thread.  You need to not do that.  And I have no idea why you're creating a new thread only to do nothing but marshal back to the UI thread to do stuff.  That whole sequence is rather pointless.

Comment: @Servy I dont see where Im blocking the UI thread. UI main thread continues normally. I want to display a waiting message to the main UI.

Comment: `calculate` Is blocking the UI thread.  That's why the UI doesn't update until it finishes; it's blocking the UI thread.

Comment: @Servy, that is my point, calculating is going to block and before it blocks I want to write some text to the UI. It has to be possible.

Comment: You need to not block the UI thread.  That's how you allow the UI to be updated.  You need to actually do your long running non-UI work asynchronously, just like you allude to in your title.

Comment: You are missing the point. If *any* part of your method is blocking the UI thread, then *nothing* will happen in the UI until your method has completed.

Comment: As @Servy noted, UI update (`txtVerification.Text = "Calculating..."`) can be done directly in `annunciate` method without creating any thread, but `calculate` should be started in separate thread

Comment: In addition to what has been said... do not use `Thread`, use `Task`.  Let CLR manage your threads.

Comment: @Servy, I dont even know what you mean now, I think you have missed completly your focus with this question.

Comment: @Elio.Batista The answers you've given are merely different techniques for doing what you're already doing in your question, namely creating a new thread and then marshaling back to the UI thread later.  All three are valid solutions, and are only different stylistically.  And of course, depending on what is actually being done in `Calculate`, it may not even be correct; if it's nothing more than long running non-UI CPU bound work, then they are all fine, but if it's say IO based work, then none of these solutions would be appropriate.

Comment: @Servy, At first calculate() was a synch call that was supposed to block the UI. I was investigating if exist the possibility to write to the UI before calling it, sort of Application.DoEvents from Winform, discussion if that is best practice is out of scope here, I just was testing. So in this site I find a similar question with an acepted and upvoted (solution?!!) with the Dispatcher.Invoke approach but was a lost of time. So I conclude that my better choice is to call calculating() asynch and write to the UI synch. I hope you got the spirit of my question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I agree with @dbvega in spirit. I cannot agree with the usage of `Task.Factory.StartNew`. Nor should you use `Dispatcher.Invoke`. By default, `Task.Factory.CurrentScheduler` will be set to the WPF message pump scheduler when running WPF. When running WinForms, there is a WinForm scheduler that is automatically set...

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBoxOutput.Text = "calculating...";

    var result = await Task.Run(Calculate);
    TextBoxOutput.Text = result.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}

private int Calculate()
{
   Thread.Sleep(2000); //--similate working....
   return Environment.TickCount ^ 43;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I went into async/await, it did the job much more cleaner than BackgroundWorker does. So easy to demostrate!!

Comment: @Aron good code if you use .NET 4.5 or a newest version. I wrote my answer using .NET 4.0. Anyway, I updated my answer. Thanks

Comment: @dbvega This code works in .net4.0 (if you rename `Task` to `TaskEx`) with the async targeting pack.

Answer (score 3):

Please, check [Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   TextBoxOutput.Text = "calculating...";

   Task.Factory
    .StartNew(() => Calculate())
    .ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        TextBoxOutput.Text = t.Result.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}

private int Calculate()
{
   Thread.Sleep(2000); //--similate working....
   return Environment.TickCount ^ 43;
}
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Good code,although my goal was simple enough, please see my answer.